# Grid's SharedSizeGroup and * sizing

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, wpf-controls, grid

I have a user control, call it `UserControl`, that has a grid with the following column definitions:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="C"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="D"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30" Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="E"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30" Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="F"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="110" SharedSizeGroup="G"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="H"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="I"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="J"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="K"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="L"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

I also have `MainWindow`, which contains a grid itself, with the following property defined on the grid:

```
Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
```

Now, I added a couple of UserControls to the grid in `MainWindow` (each to a separate row). My goal is to have each of the column widths of the different UserControls to remain in sync. Everything works fine when using `SharedSizeGroup` except for one thing. It seems that any column with a Width of `*` does not behave as it should. It looks like the `*` column widths are set as if they were `Auto` instead.

Are there any limitations/issues with `SharedSizeGroup` and `*` sizing? This seems like the best way to keep the column widths in sync but I can't seem to fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

[DefinitionBase.SharedSizeGroup Property (Microsoft Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup):

> Columns and rows that participate in
>   size-sharing do not respect Star
>   sizing. In the size-sharing scenario,
>   Star sizing is treated as Auto

If you use star then all columns would be the same width, so you should assign the same `SharedSizeGroup` to all if you do not mind the auto-sizing aspect:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="StarDontWork"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="D"/>
    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30" Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="StarDontWork"/>
    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30" Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="StarDontWork"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="110" SharedSizeGroup="G"/>
    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="H"/>
    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="I"/>
    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="J"/>
    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="K"/>
    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="L"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

(From this behavior it also follows that you can drop the `Width` property when `SharedSizeGroup` is set)

---

You can deduce that if all auto-sizing columns are in shared size groups then all star-sizing columns will have the same sizes as every grid in scope will have the same amount of unused space left that will be distributed to the star-sized columns.

A simple example:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B" Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="C"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

As explained the `Width="*"` will not do anything, but as columns `0` and `2` are synched, column `1` has to be synched as well so you can just drop the `SharedSizeGroup`:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="C"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Unfortunately, setting the * columns to use a different SharedSizeGroup will cause all of those columns to have their widths synced (which is expected) but not what I am looking for.  I need each column width to be synced individually.

Comment: What i proposed is *exactly what the star would normally do*, i don't get what you want...

Comment: Be ve-e-ery careful with this. My app, doing nothing consumed 100% of one CPU core because of this. As soon as I removed the "SharedSizeGroup" it consumes 0, as expected.

Comment: @AlexeiOst: I assume the content of the Grid changed all the time? If not that would be quite horrible, there should be no need for CPU usage if there are no layout updates.

Comment: Not necessarily. I've just encountered a case, where **in the designer** the displayed preview of the layout has fallen into 'infinite loop of update': come 3 columns have been assigned the same sharedsizegroup **and some of them** also had Width=*, and the preview rendered them with sizes, let's say: 10,10,30, then instantly it was redrawn with sizes 10,30,10, then redrawn to 10,10,30, then  10,30,10, and so on. I can easily assure you that nothing was changing behind the scenes, it was only plain layout preview. I assume that if I run that app with this, it would spin as as @AlexeiOst said.

Comment: By "the designer" I meant the preview that is available when you edit the XAML code. With few careful tricks the preview can be actually made really accurate about layout and rendering! [while surely editing via the visual designer is usually just as bad idea as it was i the WinForms designer..]

Comment: @AlexeiOst for some reason I read the first sentence of your comment in my head as Elmer Fudd.