# How to evenly space out GridViewColumns in GridView?

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview

This is my XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Property1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Property1}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Property2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Property2}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I want these 2 columns to take up the width of ListView in 1:1 ratio.

How can I achieve this?

---

Edit: I found [this suggestion on MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/377763/allow-star-sizing-for-wpf-gridviewcolumn-elements). This would perfectly solve my problem.
However it is closed as postponed (for 2.5 years now..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What comes to mind is using internal `Grids` in the templates which each have a `ColumnDefinition` with the same `SharedSizeGroup`, the `GridView` should then have `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` and the columns of the grid view should themselves be unresizable (if that is possible), cannot test that right now so it's a bit sketchy.

Another method would be to bind both `Widths` of the `GridViewColumns` to the width of the `ListView` and then use a custom converter to get an appropriate fraction of that back.

Comment: +1, Potentially Blend could be used to discover what the "template" looks like for the `GridView`, which may enable restyling the columns. However, my gut says binding the `Width` to a converter set to half the `ActualWidth` of the `ListView` is probably going to be the only way without writing his own `ViewBase`.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I tried exactly that and it gave me a horizontal scrollbar. I think I need something less than 2 halves.

Comment: @Kugel: You could just force the scrollbar to be off, you won't be needing it anyway, it's just a pixel or two :P

Comment: I tried the SharedSizeGroup solution and it had no effect.

Comment: @SimonF: See this answer in case you expected them to space out across the available space: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664008/grids-sharedsizegroup-and-sizing/4664030#4664030