# How to bind Grid row height?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have 2 identical grids with splitters:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

How to make them resize synchronously? So that row heights will be the same for both grids.

Comment: Are they located next to each other?

Comment: They are on separate tabs of TabControl

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [Shared Size Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup.aspx). Add an attribute `SharedSizeGroup="some_label"` to row or column definitions you want to resize synchronously.

Also, you need to define `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true"` for some container which contains both grids (tab control in your case).

Comment: [Possibly relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4664008/590790): _"Columns and rows that participate in size-sharing do not respect Star sizing. In the size-sharing scenario, Star sizing is treated as Auto"_

Comment: It also behaves quite strange. When I resize row in first tab I cant make its size in other tab less than in first.

Comment: I've found that it is a bug that renders this feature completely useless in my case: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/509801/wpf-sharedsizegroup-gridsplitter-bug

Comment: Any other suggestions? Maybe bind them to some common DependencyProperty?

Comment: @Poma binding with `Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` should work just ok. Just don't forget to raise PropertyChanged event inside property setter or second grid won't be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I *can* do that via simple bindings:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=MySize, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

Where MySize is

```
private GridLength mySize;
public GridLength MySize
{
    get { return mySize; }
    set
    {
        if (mySize == value) return;
        mySize = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MySize");
    }
}
```

*Note:* Mode=TwoWay is needed since unlike other conrols RowDefinition doesn't default its mode to TwoWay

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to accomplish that is programmatically:

Register the DragCompleted Event of the Gridsplitter in both grids in **XAML** and give each grid a name:

```
<GridSplitter DragCompleted="GridSplitter_DragCompleted1" Grid.Row="1" Height="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

In **CodeBehind** sync the height of the RowDefinitions. As the grisplitter is only affecting the Row/ColDefinitions of the attached rows/cols, we have to sync the rowdefinitions here. Doing other things like setting the gridsplitters position won't work.

```
private void GridSplitter_DragCompleted1(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  SyncRowDefinitions(Grid1, Grid2);
}

private void GridSplitter_DragCompleted2(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  SyncRowDefinitions(Grid2, Grid1);
}


private void SyncRowDefinitions(Grid sourceGrid, Grid targetGrid)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < sourceGrid.RowDefinitions.Count; i++)
  {
    targetGrid.RowDefinitions[i].Height = sourceGrid.RowDefinitions[i].Height;
  }
}
```

**Edit:** If needed you can Sync the grids also on other occurences like sizechanged (of the overall grid) after its initially loaded, and so on ...