# Control the width of child in Stackpanel

Tags: wpf, width, element, stackpanel

I'm trying to implement a certain layout.

I have two elements that I want to stack vertically (I need them to follow each other closely). I am currently trying to achieve it using a Stackpanel.

The problem is that I want the first element to have a limited width and the other to use all the width available in the StackPanel. Ideally, I would like that the first element have a width equals to the width of four columns from the grid that contains the StackPanel, here is my code.

```
<Grid>
<!-- Colums and Rows definition go here -->
<StackPanel  Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="8">
    //The first element
    <Viewbox Name="viewbox_choix" Margin="160,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="4">
    //The second element
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
        <Border></Border>
        etc...
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The grid attributes are referring to the parent grid of the stackpanel. But the Grid.Column and Grid.ColumnSpans seem to have no effect when I try to use them inside the StackPanel.

The problem of that code is that the first element also uses all the width of the StackPanel but that isn't what I want...

Can anybody help me ? I precise that I'm still learning WPF and I don't really know how bindings work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, a `StackPanel` does not work like a `Grid`. There is no maximum width... it will happily let content disappear out of its right side. If you want automatic resizing, just replace the `StackPanel`s with `Grid

UPDATE >>>

In the `Grid` class, there is an attached property called `IsSharedSizeScope`. Add this to the parent `Grid` and set it to true. Then in your `RowDefinitions`, you can add `SharedSizeGroup` properties to the columns that you require.

These examples may help you:

[Grid's SharedSizeGroup and * sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664008/grids-sharedsizegroup-and-sizing) (SO post)

[Grid.IsSharedSizeScope Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx) (MSDN)

You may need to experiment a bit, but you should be able to get the desired effect using these properties.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this and I'll tell you.

Comment: Well, I still have a problem actually, how can I set the Maximum Width of a row equal to the width of 4 columns of the Parent Grid ? My question is, how can I refer to the parent grid ?