# How to Center a Checkbox in a XAML DataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, datagrid

I'm trying to center a checkbox in a cell of data grid.

I can't seem to come up with a way to center it that works in different Windows themes.  I can center it, for example, so that it looks good in the Classic Windows theme, but under the Windows 7 Basic theme it is off.

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredCheckStyle}" MinWidth="15" 
CellStyle="{StaticResource SingleClickEditing}"  Visibility="{Binding exists}"
Binding="{Binding Path=toTransfer, Mode=TwoWay, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" 
CanUserSort="False" CanUserResize="false" CanUserReorder="false">
     <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Checked"  
                       HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       IsThreeState="False" Margin="8,0,0,0" Loaded="CheckBox_Loaded"/>
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Don't use that Margin 8,0,0,0...

Comment: If I leave the Margin out, it looks good in classic, and if I add it, it looks good in Windows 7 Basic

Comment: You could try a 'HeadedItemsControl' if you don't need all the DataGrid stuff, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453131/wpf-listbox-giving-columns-a-header/41751947#41751947

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set HeaderStyle property of your DG with below.
I am also new to WPF and not expert but hope it helps you in some way.

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
       <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
```