# How to create a table like ListView in AvaloniaUi?

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

How to create a table like ListView in Avalonia ui ? I sow that ListView in only planning, but I am shure that there are same variants of how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [ItemsRepeater](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/controls/itemsrepeater). It is a very flexible and easy to use control. You can generate a basic ListView like so:

XAML:

```
<ItemsRepeater Items="{Binding MyList}"></ItemsRepeater>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<String> myList = new ObservableCollection<string>(new string[] {"Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3"});
    public ObservableCollection<String> MyList
    {
        get => myList;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref myList, value);
    }
}
```

If you want your rows to be selectable / highlight them on hover, you can do all that. Check out the ItemsRepeater page in the AvaloniaUI [ControlCatalog](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/samples/ControlCatalog/Pages/ItemsRepeaterPage.xaml) for a more sophisticated sample.

Answer (score 2):

I think [ListBox](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/controls/listbox) would be a more suitable alternative than [ItemsRepeater](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/controls/itemsrepeater)

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned, there is currently no support for a ListView. Although a [ListBox](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/controls/listbox) could be an alternative for your use case.

```
<ListBox Items="{Binding MyItems}"/>
```

To get headers to work, please take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32453732/12782764).