# How to put a label inside a listbox to show contents of a textblock in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My program can scan a barcode and separate the product ID and net weight from the barcode and show it in the stackpanel. I want to add labels on top which will indicate the first part as product ID and the second part as net weight, but i cannot get it to work. Could someone point me how i can approach this?

```
<ListBox Height="300" ItemsSource="{Binding ListBarcode}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
     Color="Blue" />
        <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"
            Color="Blue" />
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding InventoryID}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="20 0 0 0" Text="{Binding Weight}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

[image: image of the seperation upon scanning the barcode]

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Please add the VIewModel code too and the code where `InventoryID` and `Weight` is declared

Comment: Solved it. I used another stackpanel on top of the current one and created two labels for the Product ID and Net Weight, and now it displays properly. The problem was, when I use it in the same textpanel, The words "Product ID" and "Net Weight" shows up right next to the scanned inputs for every line. And since it's a stackpanel, I can't dock it to the top. @SirRufo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding it in another stackpanel on top of the current one. There is no direct equivalent property for a DocPanel.Dock="Top" for StackPanel container, that was the issue.

[image: update]

```
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                        Margin="0,20,0,0">
                <Label Content="Product ID" Width="70" Height="30" Foreground="White" Margin="-340 0 0 0"/>
                <Label Content="Net Weight" Width="70" Height="30" Foreground="White" Margin="-160 -30 0 0" />
                
            </StackPanel>

            <ListBox Height="300" ItemsSource="{Binding ListBarcode}">
                <ListBox.Resources>
                    <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                     Color="Blue" />
                    <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"
                     Color="Blue" />
                </ListBox.Resources>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding InventoryID}" />
                            <TextBlock Margin="50 0 0 0" Text="{Binding Weight}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32453624/1744164