# ListBox scrollbar breaks sync columns with Grid.IsSharedSizeScope

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, sharedsizegroup, issharedsizescope

I need to show a table with headers using `ListBox`

I searched on the web about how to create this and i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781411/how-do-i-make-a-header-for-a-listboxitem) answer, here is the XAML code i created:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="6*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="quantityColumn"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="priceColumn"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="editColumn"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="deleteColumn"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Foreground="#5a5a5a" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">Cantidad</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Foreground="#5a5a5a" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">Precio</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Foreground="#5a5a5a" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">Descripción</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Foreground="#5a5a5a" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">Editar</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Foreground="#5a5a5a" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">Eliminar</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Name="OrderList" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ManipulationBoundaryFeedback="OrderList_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                <EventSetter Event="RequestBringIntoView" Handler="ListBoxItem_RequestBringIntoView"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="quantityColumn"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="priceColumn"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="editColumn"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="deleteColumn"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="7">Cantidad</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="7">Precio</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="7">Descripción</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="7">Editar</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="7">Eliminar</TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

And here is the c# code i created to test and populate the `ListBox`

```
List<OrderItem> orders = new List<OrderItem>();
orders.Add(new OrderItem() { a = "wash", b = "b" });
orders.Add(new OrderItem() { a = "the", b = "c" });
orders.Add(new OrderItem() { a = "car", b = "d" });
orders.Add(new OrderItem() { a = "wash", b = "b" });
OrderList.ItemsSource = orders;
```

Since the `ListBox` only shows 4 rows, it doesnt have to set a scrollbar, and the headers are almost 100% aligned with the table columns:

[image]

The problem worsens when i add more rows to the `ListBox` and the scrollbar appears:

[image]

As you can see the offset of each column with its header its too big. How can i tell the `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` to be aware of the width of the scrollbar and to consider it to the headers width? What i need it's to have the table columns 100% aligned with the table headers.

Comment: Try setting the Margin and Padding of ListViewItem.

Comment: @user1672994 If i add a margin, the listbox with the scrollbar will look perfect, but without the scrollbar will look bad.

Comment: I think DataGrid is more practical to use based on what you are trying to achieve. Sharing of size is effective within siblings in VisualTree. The ListBox' items Grid in here becomes the 'niece' of the outer Grid.

Comment: Is this tasked solved? An answer would be helpful