# ItemsControl with SharedSizeGroup AND stretching

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol, itemtemplate, sharedsizegroup

Apparently when using a SharedSizeGroup, you can't use star sizing (*).  This has been discussed here:
[Grid's SharedSizeGroup and * sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664008/grids-sharedsizegroup-and-sizing)

Unfortunately, in that discussion they don't really offer a viable solution to the problem.

I would like to display a list of controls, one control per row, with the following layout:

(Name)(Entry textbox)(X Button)

It should look like this:

```
Description [                     ] X
Name        [                     ] X
ID          [                     ] X
```

But instead I'm getting

```
Description [] X
Name        [] X
ID          [] X
```

Column 1 should be as wide as the longest word. Column 2, the entry textbox, should stretch to fill all the remaining space (*), but that doesn't work with SharedSizeGroup as previously discussed.  The * is being treated as Auto, hence the non-stretching.

Any ideas?  Here's the XAML:

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FilterList}" Margin="5,0,5,0" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="5,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Column0" Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Column1" Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Column2" Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding FilterLabel}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding FilterString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="2" Content=" X " Margin="2" Visibility="{Binding ClearFilterVis}" Command="{Binding ClearFilterCommand}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: second column: `<ColumnDefinition/>` will take all the available space. You don't need sharedsizegroup in that case, nor `Width="*"`

Comment: Tried that.  I still get the problem described above.  It's shrinking to only take up as much space as the empty text boxes take, which is not much.  In other words, it's acting like the first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you set `Grid's HorizontalAlignment` to Left instead of Stretch. Or just remove `Grid's HorizontalAlignment` setting. And as @Highcore said, you don't seems to need `SharedSizeGroup` in this case.

Comment: Yes, it was a combination of the two problems.  I had tried the stretch alignment before, but with the SharedSizeGroup being set, it was still not working.  Thanks!