# WPF Grids inside ListView and header appear have inconsistent sizes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, .net-core

I have grids in List View item template and in a header grid. This is a the code for that section.

`

```
            <!--Products listview headers-->
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                           Text="Order No" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                           Text="Customer" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
                           Text="Total"                                             
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </Grid>

            <Border Style="{StaticResource HRule}" />


            <!--Products listview-->

            <ListView x:Name="listView" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding SalesOrders}" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSalesOrder, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      Padding="0"
                      Margin="0">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
                            <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightCyan"/>
                            <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="LightGray" />
                        </Style.Resources>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type entities:SalesOrder}">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                       Text="{Binding No, StringFormat={StaticResource serialNoFormat}}" 
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                       Text="{Binding Customer.Name}" 
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
                                       Text="{Binding Total, StringFormat={StaticResource currencyFormat}}"                                             
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>`
```

Currently the columns do not align in the header and the rows. It currently looks like this.
[image]

I could not find the reason for the misalignment.

I tried setting the padding and margin of the listview to 0. But it did not work. I tried shared size scoping for the grids but did not have any luck either.

Comment: Have you considered using the <Table> element?

Comment: Have you considered a gridview or datagrid?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/gridview-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Grid and List View utilise GridView with your ListView.
So:

```
<ListView>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Order No">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock
                                   Text="{Binding No, StringFormat={StaticResource serialNoFormat}}" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Customer">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock 
                                   Text="{Binding Customer.Name}" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Total">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock
                                   Text="{Binding Total, StringFormat={StaticResource currencyFormat}}"                                             
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Give this a go and see if it does what you need it to do.

Comment: If there is not other option I could use it, but I cannot use star sizing with GridView right? Thats an issue

Comment: You can use a grid outside and as a shared size element. Have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664008/grids-sharedsizegroup-and-sizing)